# How do I post PayPal array response details to database using Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, paypal

How do I post this Paypal response details to database

I have succefully made payment using smart button paypal.

I am able to capture the response details using console log.

Now How do I post the response array to database using laravel.

**Onapproval**

```
onApprove: function(data, actions) {

      let token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content');

      // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
          if(details.status == 'COMPLETED'){
            return fetch('/pages/save', {
                      method: 'post',
                      headers: {
                          'content-type': 'application/json',
                          "Accept": "application/json, text-plain, */*",
                          "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                          "X-CSRF-TOKEN": token
                      },
                      body: JSON.stringify({
                          orderId     : data.orderID,
                          id : details.id,
                          status: details.status,
                          payerEmail: details.payer.email_address,
                      })
                  })
                  .then(status)
                  .then(function(response){
                      // redirect to the completed page if paid
                      console.log(details)
                      // window.location.href = '/pages/sucess';
                  })
                  .catch(function(error) {
                      // redirect to failed page if internal error occurs
                      window.location.href = '/pages/fail?reason=internalFailure';
                  });
          }else{
              window.location.href = '/pages/fail?reason=failedToCapture';
          }
      });
    },
```

**Laravel route**

```
Route::get('pages/sucess', [App\Http\Controllers\OrderController::class, 'sucess'])->name('pages.sucess');
```

**Output**

```
{
    "id": "9S369747UW261581G",
    "intent": "CAPTURE",
    "status": "COMPLETED",
    "purchase_units": [
        {
            "reference_id": "default",
            "amount": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "0.50"
            },
           
            "shipping": {
                "name": {
                    "full_name": "John Doe"
                },
               
            },
            "payments": {
                "captures": [
                    {
                        "id": "5DS42883V93959154",
                        "status": "COMPLETED",
                        "amount": {
                            "currency_code": "USD",
                            "value": "0.50"
                        },
                       
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    
}
```

How can one capture PayPal response details and dump the same detail to the Laravel controller so that it can be saved to the database?

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* use `actions.order.create() / .capture()` on the client side and then post information to a database.

Instead, change to a proper server-side integration. Make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). When a capture response is successful, store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) before sending your return JSON.

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: @Dominic you can use guzzlehttp for that or Http client wrapper by laravel